# Εxpress n is the kth prime using a logic formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Assume I already have defined `prime(n)` which tells whether n is a prime and `cons_prime(n,m)` which tells whether m,n are coprimes.

I need to define a formula for `P(n,k)`  which is true if and only if n is the kth prime .

I've been thinking something like :
$$P(k,n) = (n=2 \wedge k = 1) \lor \exists m(P(k-1,m) \wedge \text{cons_prime}(m,n))$$